# CrossMedia Plugin Only Opens Picture mode instead of Video

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a button in my xamarin application where I want to be able to record a video. The only problem is that when I click on it, it takes the camera instead of video (see photo).
[image: This is what I got]
This is the method I am currently using.

```
private async Task TakeVideoAndSave()
        {
            if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakeVideoSupported)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("No Camera", "No camera avaialble.", "OK");
                return;
            }

            var createdInAppOn = _declaration.CreatedInAppOn.Value.ToString("s").Replace(":", string.Empty);
            var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
            var videoPath = Path.Combine(path, createdInAppOn + ".mp4");
            var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakeVideoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreVideoOptions
            {
                Name = createdInAppOn + ".mp4",
                Quality = VideoQuality.Low,
            });

            if (file == null)
                return;

            await DisplayAlert("Video Recorded", "Location: " + file.Path, "OK");

            file.Dispose();
        }
```

How do I manage to get the video camera from android instead of the photo camera?

Thanks in advance

Comment: CrossMedia has been deprecated and is not being maintained.  You need to look into Xamarin Essentials MediaManager

Comment: can you give me a example or a source how to record video using xamarin essentials?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/media-picker?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android#using-media-picker

Answer (score 0):

The **MediaPicker** class lets a user pick or take a photo or video on the device.

You can use **CaptureVideoAsync** which Opens the camera to take a video.

Here is the API documentation of MediaPicker:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.essentials.mediapicker?view=xamarin-essentials